# date format validation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to validate the date format (from datepicker) If the date format is right then go to next step if wrong then alert

```
if ($("#date").val() != (/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/)) {
  $("#date").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
}
else {
  alert("good");
}
```

But this script does not work

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Tried `$("#date").val().match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/) != null` ?

Comment: nothing. any alert message. if i put right date format still nothing

Comment: what does "is right" mean? The answer to that question is likely half the answer to the one you posted.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 01/08/2014 right 01-08/14 not right

Comment: @M1K1O Solve thank you. Should be == null

Comment: note the code you have isn't useful javascript right now: you're comparing a string to a regular expression, which is simply always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try :

```
if (!/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test($("#date").val())) {
  $("#date").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
}
else {
  alert("good");
}
```

You can't compare a string to a RegExp object with `==` or `!=` operators, you have to use Regexp methods. [see mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: I'm sorry but copy pasting from where ?

Comment: from Edwards post. By the time he have edit it but it was the same post all the time. and it was 3 mins earlyer :)

Comment: I didn't saw his post, I openened a jsbin, tested the code there, and posted it directly. To be honest the snippet is so small there isn't much space for originality.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if (!(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/).test($("#date").val())) {
  $("#date").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
}
else {
  alert("good");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code helps:

```
function call()
{
    if ($("#date").val().search((/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/))>-1) {
        $("#date").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    }
    else {
        alert("good");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and answers your question and also for this thread. :)