# date format check with regex Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a form when submitted checks for null value and incorrect format of data. The issue here is even when the format is correct it throws the error. 
The date format i want is dd/mm/yyyy.

```
$("#sche_inter_form").submit(function(e){
if( ($("#inter_date").val()==="") || checkdateFormat()) {
     $("#inter_date").css({"border-bottom":" 1px solid #dd4b39"});
     e.preventDefault(e);
     }
function checkdateFormat(){
   var date = $("#inter_date").val();
   console.log(date);
   var re= new RegExp("/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d+$/");
     var result = re.test(date);
     if (result) {
        return false;
            }
     else{
        return true;
         }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [date format validation with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075418/date-format-validation-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I validate a date in this format (yyyy-mm-dd) using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758772/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-this-format-yyyy-mm-dd-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not matching a sample date like `11/11/2000`.

Use this regex:

```
new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)[0-9]{2,}$")
```

Comment: @NaveenKumar The `/`'s surrounding the regex are not required in `RegExp()`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: But without that it throws error unexpected token *caret symbol*